# Graph theory: Components of a vertex set

Tags: graph-theory

Let *G* be the graph with vertex set $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in which vertices *u, v* satisfy the adjacency relation iff *u* and *v* differ by 6. For each $n\geqq 1$, determine the number of components of *G*.

I think that if *n*<12, there will be n components with no adjacency relation, and if *n*=12, there will be 6 components that are each disjoint sets *u* and *v*, but I am struggling with *n*>12. Can anyone help?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56699/discussion-on-question-by-mike-graph-theory-components-of-a-vertex-set). **I RECOMMEND THAT ANYONE WANTING TO ANSWER THIS QUESTION TAKE A PEEK AT THE CHAT** Some essential information came gradually to light (but the exchange is too long to be kept here). TL; DR; Assuming "differ by 6" means "differ by 6 modulo $n$", which IMO is the intended meaning. For otherwise the vertex set would surely have been given as $$\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}_n$.